# SQL & VBScripts: How to store an SQL query column (USER_FIRSTNAME) into a VBScript variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, vbscript

I tried to get this working but it isn't working and therefore was wondering if anyone one here would be able to help me fix this issue. Problem is that I can't get the SQL query column to store into a VBScript variable after the select statement has ran. I simply want the user's firstname and lastname to be stored into a variable where user_id and password matches in the database when SQL query runs. So that I can display their name like welcome "firstname, lastname". My database does connect to the database and everything but I just don't know how to store that certain persons name from oracle to VBScript variable which I can display on that same page saying welcome John Smith or something.

Please don't worry about SQL Injection stuff, it is not needed at this moment.

Following is the ASP file code:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>

<%user_id=Request("user_id") user_pwd=Request("user_pwd") %>

<% Set DBConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   DBConn.Open "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};DBQ=ORCL;UID=ops$dbID;PWD=dbPWD;"
   Login = "SELECT USER_ID, USER_FIRSTNAME, USER_SURNAME FROM UserTable WHERE USER_ID = '" & user_id & "' AND USER_PWD='"& user_pwd &"';"

   Set QueryResult = DBConn.Execute(QueryToRun)

   QueryResult.Close

   DBConn.Close
%>
```

I even tried `response.write("USER_FIRSTNAME")` and still it doesn't work because it needs to be stored into a variable first from the query which I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: ASP is not PHP. ASP is not Asp.Net.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to query an oracle database and return a data reader, which you can then iterate over, in VB:

```
data_source = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};DBQ=ORCL;UID=ops$dbID;PWD=dbPWD;"
Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open data_source
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sqlread = "SELECT USER_ID, USER_FIRSTNAME, USER_SURNAME FROM UserTable WHERE USER_ID = '" & user_id & "' AND USER_PWD='"& user_pwd &"';"

rs.Open sqlread, con
Do while not rs.eof
  FName=rs.fields("USER_FIRSTNAME")
rs.Movenext
Loop
```

Comment: this hasn't solved my problem, if you see my code there should be only one or two line that needs to be added so that first name can be stored into a variable and then i can use response.write(firstnameVariable) which will simply display the name of the user. You have made it complicated. it isn't very complicated, i know it isn't but i just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Some times the right way is more complicated (although, in this example it really isn't).  Either way, I provided a an example that you can use.  Look your variable "QueryResult".  I imagine the results from your query are being put into there.  Try to iterate over it like I did in my example (While dr.read...)

Comment: Sorry, actually you mislabeled your question.  I assumed it was for a .Net application but it really is VBScript.  I removed the tags from your question and you should get better results.